# Crear una vista que muestre solo precios que supere la media de los precios en la tabla productos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas, una de moviles que tiene registros de codigoproducto, nombre, año, pais y año. La otra tabla es de Productos con el codigoproducto y el precio. En la vista tiene que aparecer en codigoproducto, nombre y precio en orden descendente. Hasta ahi lo he hecho yo pero ahora mi pregunta es como hacer para que en esta vista me aparezcan solo los precios que son mayores que la media en la tabla Productos. EJ en la tabla Productos el precio medio es 500, pues en la vista necesito hacer que solo aparezcan los productos que superan los 500.
No se si me he explicado bien, perdon.

Comment: ¿Cual es la sentencia `SQL` actual que tienes para "traerte" los datos desde la base de datos?

Comment: CREATE VIEW `ModelosAntiguos` AS SELECT 
` codigodelproducto`, `nombre` FROM `móviles`
 RIGHT JOIN `productos` ON móviles.codigodelproducto = productos.codigodelproducto 
 ORDER BY `precio` DESC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solventar este problema bastará con modificar la sentencia `SQL` que estás utilizando para obtener los datos para añadir una subconsulta en la clausula `WHERE`.

De tal forma la sentencia quedaría así:

```
SELECT ` codigodelproducto, nombre` FROM móviles RIGHT JOIN productos ON móviles.codigodelproducto = productos.codigodelproducto WHERE productos.precio > (SELECT AVG(precio) FROM productos) ORDER BY precio DESC;
```

Comment: okey okey si cierto, me faltaba el where con AVG bin bien merciii